# SOLR last modified different than filesystem last modified

Tags: linux, solr

I am indexing a bunch of PDF's, Docs, PPT's etc with Solr cell.  When I retrieve the records each has a last-modified value, but the value is different than what I see on the file system using ls -la.  Aren't those supposed to match, and if not, how can I retrieve the same values for each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apache Tika documentation](https://tika.apache.org/0.5/formats.html), what is probably happening is that the last modified date is being pulled from the document metadata, not the file system.  This may be more accurate if, for instance, the document isn't uploaded to your site until a week after it was actually changed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347086/get-file-system-metadata-with-solr is a new question, but if an answer is found will solve your question too.

Comment: Thank you.  This answer is enough to tell me I'm trying the wrong approach.  Setting up DIH is probably a better approach:  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler